change error message of next js image optimizaion api
i have project with next js 13.4 and using its default image optimization api and component, security department wants me to hide error messages related to path like:
/_next/image?...

right now for example with 400 error it shows this message:
unable to optimize image and unable to fallback to upstream image

i must some how prevent showing deatils of the issue that next shows when somthing is wrong,
i host it on windows with custom server if it helps and try to cache error but not falls in cache part.

Easiest solution is probably not a code solution but another layer, e.g. nginx reverse proxy. But personally I might push back on this one

thanks but i hosted it on windows

I don't understand why that matters. You can run nginx on Windows. Or you could put another machine running nginx in front of your windows box

I want to prevent this message with coding, i cant put the responsibility on an other team like infrustructure

That's reasonable!
